# Oracle Procedure error "declaration of cursor 'C' us incomplete or malformed"?

Tags: oracle, syntax, compiler-errors, cursor

When I try to run procedure `printshipment` I get an error

```
PLS-00341: declaration of cursor 'C' is incomplete or malformed
```

What is wrong with my cursor declaration and how to fix it?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE printshipment(onmbr  IN shipment.onum%TYPE,
                                          shnmbr IN shipment.snum%TYPE)
IS
  CURSOR c IS
    SELECT
      shcontent.inum  ino,
      item.descr      description,
      item.qtyshipped q,
      item.unitprice  u,
      u * q           cost
     FROM shcontent, item
    WHERE shcontent.snum = shnmbr
      AND shcontent.onum = onmbr
      AND shcontent.inum = item.inum;

  rec c%ROWTYPE;

  BEGIN

    OPEN c;

    FETCH c INTO rec;

    IF c%NOTFOUND THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('No Shipment');
    END IF;

    CLOSE c;   
  END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to include variable parameters in the cursor's query you have to declare it as a parameterized cursor, like this:

```
CURSOR C (c_onmbr IN Shipment.onum%type, c_shnmbr IN Shipment.snum%type)
IS 
  SELECT ShContent.inum Ino, Item.descr description, Item.Qtyshipped Q,   
      Item.UnitPrice U, U * Q COST
  FROM ShContent, Item
  WHERE ShContent.snum = c_shnmbr
    AND ShContent.onum = c_onmbr
    AND ShContent.inum = Item.inum;
```

and then

```
OPEN C(onmbr, shnmbr);
```

I may be mistaken, though; my Oracle certs *are* a bit out-of-date.

Comment: I think you are mistaken, variables can be referenced in the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

Column aliases cannot be reference in the same SELECT list.  Unless "q" and "u" are also columns in the tables, this part of the statement is invalid:

```
  item.qtyshipped q,
  item.unitprice  u,
  u * q           cost
```

Either replace `u * q` with `item.qtyshipped * item.unitprice` or wrap the SELECT statement in another inline view and then reference the aliases.  Also, there is probably some more information in the error message(s).  Always post the entire error message when there's a problem.